# Disable alphabetical execution order of triggers

Tags: postgresql, trigger

I would like to disable alphabetical order of triggers firing. Is it possible?

The reason I need this is to show in my studies why it is important to take care of triggers' execution order. However, I cannot find any way to disable this order and allow triggers race.

Comment: as I understand - it is fundamentals and no any methods to change this

Comment: Good question, but it's not possible. For your studies, I can recommend creating a test case using a BEFORE and AFTER trigger, and swapping them round manually to prove your point. It's easy to come up with situations that'll go horribly wrong if they're the wrong way round :)

Comment: can't use some prefix like a00_, a01_, a02_ to fix the order?

Comment: fixed order is still not race...